# Laravel Dynamic Fillable in Models

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5, models

Got stuck in a issue with laravel 5.2.

Following is the error during eloquent create operation(post call),

Mass Assignment Exception in Model.php 453: column_name

Following are the prerequisites, which are to be taken into consideration:

1. Fillables in model are filled in a dynamic manner by the following code:

   ```
   public function __construct() {
        $this->fillable(\Schema::getColumnListing($this->getTable()))
   }
   ```

Following are the methods which are debugged till now:

1. Before insertion, in controller, $model::getillableField(), gives proper fillable array.
2. In model.php line(450),

   ```
   if ($this->isFillable($key)) {
         $this->setAttribute($key, $value);
   }
   ```

   the above code returns the value as "false" and $model::getFillableField() has the column_name in the array list.
3. Hardcoding $fillable variable with columns of table removes the error.
   Please Help, where i am going wrong and what is the solution for it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you are really trying to do is make *ALL* fields fillable.

The correct way to do this in Laravel is this:

```
protected $guarded = [];
```

This works in 5.2, even though the documentation for it is found in 5.3.

([relevant source code for 5.2](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L2352-L2355))

([Documentation from 5.3](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent)):

> If you would like to make all attributes mass assignable, you may define the $guarded property as an empty array:

By setting `$guarded` to an empty array, you are creating an empty black list, allowing all fields to be mass assignable.

Also, if this model is ***ever*** going to be constructed directly from user input, please do not do this. Laravel requires either `$fillable` or `$guarded` to be defined for a reason. Unless your model has fields that are literally 1:1 with a public form, then allowing all fields to be writable on mass assignment is a security vulnerability.

Comment: If I try to save a column that doesn't exist in my schema, laravel is going to throw a mysql exception instead of mapping only to those that exist.

Answer (score 10):

Try this.
Put the below code in your model,

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->setFillable();
}
public function setFillable()
{
    $fields = \Schema::getColumnListing('table_name_here');

    $this->fillable[] = $fields;
}
```

This makes each and every column is fillable from that table.

Answer (score 7):

Create a trait that uses the database columns.

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

trait ColumnFillable
{
    public function getFillable()
    {
        return Schema::getColumnListing($this->getTable());
    }
}
```

Now use this trait in your models.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use App\Traits\ColumnFillable;

class MyModel extends Model
{
    use ColumnFillable;

    ...
```

Now you'll never have to manually specify `$fillable`.

Comment: Make sure you know that this hits the database. Maybe everytime a Model is initialized.